# putting the content type into the list

Tags: content-type, custom-list

I have created two content types for my list, which take you to two different forms some items the same some different.
Is there anyway to show what content type was selected in the list. Maybe by creating a column and having the default value change depending on which content type was selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have already a "content type" column; it is enough to make it visible in your form.